# Logic Failed when using System Date

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a Gym management system in windows form ( .Net ) . In this I check a user last pay fee date with current System date when application is start if current date is 30 days greater than last fee pay date then user will be able to pay fee .. but my problem is this if user change a system date than my logic is failed what I do please suggest me ?? (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: What behavior do you expect in that case?

Comment: Why would you allow users to change the system date on a computer used to calculate how much money they owe?

Comment: This should not be localized on a personal computer. Should calculate on a host computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for operators who are working for the gym, tell them not to mess up machines they are meant to be keeping in a reasonable state to work with.

If this is for users themselves don't give them an application that let's them deal with this sort of thing, use a client-server approach, and go by the server's date. And for that matter, why an executable rather than just a web-page?

Comment: The go with the first sentence above.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to consider an external source, such as a service call to a trusted source of time-keeping (aka time server).  You might want to consider signing the response as well to prevent spoofing attacks.

There are simply too many ways from the client side that the clock could be manipulated, so your best bet is to use a client/server approach.  (And since you haven't mentioned anything about how the client is configured, we can't help you much further).